# How to implement Index over a wrapped HashMap?

Tags: rust

I would like to implement the Index trait for a wrapper type over the HashMap type:

```
use std::collections::HashMap;
use std::option::Option;

#[cfg(test)]
use std::ops::Index;

#[derive(Debug, Clone)]
struct Value {
    val: i32,
}

#[derive(Debug, Clone)]
pub struct HMShadow {
    hashmap: HashMap<String, Value>,
}

impl HMShadow {
    fn new() -> HMShadow {
        HMShadow {
            hashmap: {
                HashMap::<String, Value>::new()
            },
        }
    }

    fn insert<S>(&mut self, key: S, element: Value) -> Option<Value>
        where S: Into<String>
    {
        self.hashmap.insert(key.into(), element)
    }

    fn get(&mut self, key: &str) -> &mut Value {
        self.hashmap.get_mut(key).expect("no entry found for key")
    }
}

fn main()
{
    let mut s: HMShadow = HMShadow::new();
    let v: Value = Value { val : 5 };
    let _ = s.insert("test", v);
    println!("{:?}", s);
    println!("Get: {}", s.get("test").val);
}

#[cfg(test)]
impl<'a> Index<&'a str> for HMShadow {
    type Output = &'a mut Value;

    fn index(&self, key: &'a str) -> &&'a mut Value {
        match self.hashmap.get_mut(key) {
            Some(val) => &mut val,
            _ => panic!("no entry found for key"),
        }
    }
}

#[cfg(test)]
#[test]
fn test_index() {
    let mut s: HMShadow = HMShadow::new();
    let v: Value = Value { val : 5 };
    let _ = s.insert("test", v);
    println!("{:?}", s);
    println!("Index: {}", s["test"].val);
}
```

Doing `rustc --test tt.rs` the compiler says:

> ```
> error[E0495]: cannot infer an appropriate lifetime for autoref due to conflicting requirements
>   --> tt.rs:51:28
>    |
> 51 |         match self.hashmap.get_mut(key) {
>    |                            ^^^^^^^
>    |
> help: consider using an explicit lifetime parameter as shown: fn index(&'a self, key: &'a str) -> &&'a mut Value
>   --> tt.rs:50:5
>    |
> 50 |     fn index(&self, key: &'a str) -> &&'a mut Value {
>    |     ^
> ```

But I cannot do `fn index(&'a self, key: &'a str) -> &&'a mut Value` because the Index trait does not allow `&'a self` and the compiler errors:

> error[E0308]: method not compatible with trait

Comment: `Some(val) => &mut val,` here, `val` is a local variable, so we can't return a reference to it. Can you explain more about what you want to do?

Comment: It is absolutely unclear what you are asking. Could you rephrase your question? Right now it sounds like: "this program doesn't compile, please help". What are you actually trying to achieve?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since your question is pretty unclear, I will reinterpret it as follows:

> I am trying to implement `Index` for my struct, but somehow it doesn't work.

#### The errors

After looking at the compiler errors, it became clear that your implementation of `Index` is wrong for many reasons:

1. The `Index` trait defines a function called `index`, which returns an *immutable* reference to the value. However, you are trying to return a *mutable* reference. Of course, Rust complains that the method you are implementing is incompatible with the trait.
2. The `Output` associated type of your `Index` implementation should not be wrapped in a reference. Therefore, instead of `type Output = &'a mut Value;` you need `type Output = Value;`
3. The lifetimes of `key` and the output in the `index` function are unrelated, but you use `'a` for both.
4. You need to make the `Value` type public in order to use it in a trait implementation.

#### The code

A correct and simple implementation of `Index` would be:

```
impl<'a> Index<&'a str> for HMShadow {
    type Output = Value;

    fn index(&self, key: &'a str) -> &Value {
        &self.hashmap[key]
    }
}
```

Comment: You may want to take a look at the `Deref` trait. If you implement it for your wrapper struct, you could get all methods from `HashMap` for free.

Comment: (you even get the nice square bracket syntax for indexing)

Answer (score 2):

I guess, I was looking for

```
#[cfg(test)]
impl<'a> IndexMut<&'a str> for HMShadow {
    fn index_mut<'b>(&'b mut self, key: &'a str) -> &'b mut Value {
        self.hashmap.get_mut(key).expect("no entry found for key")
    }
}
```